# Expected type mismatch with if expression in Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin

I wonder if somebody can help me to fix this issue with mismatched types inside the  if expression by using Kotlin?

I have 2 activities to connect between the:
The first activity is `MainActivity.kt` and the second activity is `Main2Activity.kt`, inside first activity `MainActivity class` i got a problem for `mismatched types`, because i'm using if statement to choose `specific image` to be convert to the `specific adapter` in the second activity like when click on image (`a`) to be converted to the 2nd activity with `ADAPTER_TYPE_1` and image (`b`) converted to the 2nd activity with `ADAPTER_TYPE_2`

Note: image type is `Int`, my first image named `a` inside my `Drawable` and the second image named `b`

**Here is a MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var adapter:FoodAdapter?=null
var listOfFoods =ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout.activity_main)


    // load foods
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", a))
    listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", b))


    adapter= FoodAdapter(this,listOfFoods)

    gvListFood.adapter =adapter

}


class  FoodAdapter: BaseAdapter {
    var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
    var context: Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, foodView: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        var inflator = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView= inflator.inflate(layout.food_ticket, null)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)


            if (foodView.ivFoodImage == a){
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_1.ordinal)
                intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
                intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
                intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }
            if (foodView.ivFoodImage == b) {
                intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_2.ordinal)
                intent.putExtra("name", food.name)
                intent.putExtra("des", food.des)
                intent.putExtra("image", food.image)

                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }





        }
        return foodView
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return listOfFood.size
    }

}
}
```

[image: error image]

**Here is Food class**

```
 class Food(val name: String, val des: String, val image: Int)
```

Comment: Kindly Provide Error Log here

Comment: I think here is problem you passing a in Int variable which is wrong `listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is", a))`

Comment: You should state at least, what you actually want to do. The `also` doesn't have any effect here. The problem you face is, that `ImageView` is not a `Boolean`. So you have to compare things somehow; but it's not clear what to at the moment. What is `a` or `b`?

Comment: Ohh, and have a look at [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

Comment: @Rajesh Dalsaniya, yes i pass in Int variable because i have images to represent inside my Food class
but i can't Access to the specific image like image `a` or `b` by using if statement

Comment: @tynn doesn't matter to use `also` i gonna remove it to appear more clear and update my question without using also, Actually my first image named `a` inside my Drawable and the second image named `b` and i want to convert from first activity to 2nd activity when click on image (a) to be converted to the 2nd activity with `ADAPTER_TYPE_1` and image (b) converted to the 2nd activity with `ADAPTER_TYPE_2` because my  2nd activity has 2 adapter inside it

Comment: @tynn Note: my first activity is `MainActivity.kt` the main issue of that i can't access to image `a` or `b` by using if statement because it's show me error, and i will be appreciated if  you add your answer

Comment: Actually i wanna click on specific image like image `a` or `b` to be converted to the  specific part  of second activity like `ADAPTER_TYPE_1` or `ADAPTER_TYPE_2` because i'm using 2 adapters, and my question been updated for `Food class` and `MainActivity` without using `java-style` and `nullable` types and i add a picture to show you error line, please any help @tynn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the resource id of the drawable you added to the image view. For specifying this you can use the *id* or even better the *tag*. In you case you even have this information with your *food* entity and should use it here.

```
class FoodAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val listOfFood: ArrayList<Food>
): BaseAdapter {

    override fun getView(p0: Int, foodView: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        val inflator = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        return inflator.inflate(layout.food_ticket, null).also {
            it.ivFoodImage.imageResource = food.image
            it.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener { view ->

                context.startActivity(Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
                    .putExtra("name", food.name)
                    .putExtra("des", food.des)
                    .putExtra("image", food.image)
                    .also {
                        when (food.image) {
                            a -> it.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_1.ordinal)
                            b -> it.putExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_ADAPTER_MODE, AdapterType.ADAPTER_TYPE_2.ordinal)
                            else -> it
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int) = listOfFood[p0]

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int) = p0.toLong()

    override fun getCount() = listOfFood.size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to think in kotlin-way, i.e. try to not use nullable types. Also your class Food written in java-style but it can be written in more simple style:
`class Food(val name: String, val des: String, val image: Int)`

When you override java methods often you can remove '?' from parameter type in order to throw away '!!' in future moments when requires not-null type.
var class property is not desirable because it gives state that you need to watch that nothing happens in runtime.

Probably tips above will resolve your issues.
If no, can you give more information about this error?(e.g. line number of error)

Comment: thank you @ Alexandr Tolstikov, Actually i did but it's still show me error and my question been updated for `Food class` and `MainActivity` without  using java-style and `nullable` types and i add a picture to show you error line, please can you help me